# flutter, search list with two words and compare this words to literable

Tags: flutter, dart

i have problem i need to search product by string, but i want to use multiple string and return list only when separated word are both contain.

i write code but not working.

```
`void search(String value) {
    List<Product> searchList = [];
    List<String> listString = value.split(' ');
    searchList.addAll((_listToSearch
        .where((product) => listString.every((element) =>
            element.toLowerCase().contains(product.name!.toLowerCase())))
        .toList()));

    setState(() {
      _listToShow = searchList;
    });
  }
```

my previous version working but show all product witch one word
`

```
  void search(String value) {
    setState(() {
      List<Product>searchList = [];
      value.split(' ').forEach((word) {
        _listToShow.addAll((_listToSearch
            .where((element) => element.name!.toLowerCase().contains(
                  word.toLowerCase(),
                ))
            .toList()));
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to search for products that contain all the words in the search string. The first version of your search function is **almost** correcto. U just need to modify the condition inside the where method by checking if every word in listString is contained in the product's name, rather than if the word contains the product's name. Here's the modified version of the search function:

```
  List<Product> searchList = [];
  List<String> listString = value.split(' ');

  searchList.addAll(_listToSearch.where((product) => listString.every((element) => product.name!.toLowerCase().contains(element.toLowerCase()))).toList());

  setState(() {
    _listToShow = searchList;
  });
}
```

This code should correctly filter the products based on the presence of all the words in the search string. When you call the search function, it will iterate through the products in _listToSearch, and for each product, it will check if all the words in listString are contained in the product's name. If this condition is true for a product, it will be added to the searchList. Finally, the _listToShow variable is updated to display the search results.